# How to make UIButton's text alignment center? Using IB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I can't set the title of UIButton using IB as center. My title is multi line.
It is giving like this one
 [image]

But I want like this one
 [image]

I have given space in this but I don't want to do that. As it is not aligned exactly for some cases and I know there is a property of UILabel to set the alignment but I don't want to write a code for that.. just want to set everything from IB.

Thanks

Comment: Kumar Rathor - try by code `self.yourButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;`

Comment: @Spark I know how to do this by code but what I wanted is to set it using 'IB'.

Comment: I know, you'd like to set it using IB. But such property is only accessible via code.

Comment: It's accessible via IB by making it attributed but who cares about that!

Comment: @YoussefSami yes you're right http://stackoverflow.com/a/5865500/468724

Comment: You can also use "Line Break" property

Answer (score 99, accepted):

### Solution1

You can set the key path in the storyboard

Set the text to your multiline title e.g. `hello`  <kbd>⌥</kbd>  + <kbd>↵</kbd> `multiline`

You need to press  <kbd>⌥</kbd>  + <kbd>↵</kbd> to move text to next line.

[image]

Then add the key path

`titleLabel.textAlignment` as `Number` and value `1`, `1` means `NSTextAlignmentCenter`
`titleLabel.numberOfLines` as `Number` and value `0`, `0` means any number of lines

[image]

**This will not be reflected on IB/Xcode, but will be in centre at run time (device/simulator)**

If you want to see the changes on Xcode you need to do the following: (remember you can skip these steps)

1. Subclass the UIButton to make the button designable:

   ```
   import UIKit
   @IBDesignable class UIDesignableButton: UIButton {}
   ```
2. Assign this designable subclass to the buttons you're modifying:

[image: Showing how to change the class of the button using Interface Builder]

3. Iff done right, you will see the visual update in IB when the Designables state is "Up to date" (which can take several seconds):

[image: Comparing the designable and default button in Interface Builder]

---

### Solution2

**If you want to write the code, then do the long process**

1.Create `IBOutlet` for button
2.Write code in viewDidLoad

```
btn.titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
btn.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

---

### Solution3

In newer version of xcode (mine is xcode 6.1) we have property attributed title
Select `Attributed` then select the text and press centre option below

**P.S.** The text was not coming multiline for that I have to set the

`btn.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0`

[image]

Comment: For solution 3, you can just add `Line Breaking = Clip`, it will transform the text to multiline

Comment: Solution 3 has problem, at least with Xcode 11.3.1: when I change button's title, it doesn't work. when I used `btn.titleLabel.textAlignment`, it works great.

Answer (score 203):

This will make exactly what you were expecting:

**Objective-C:**

```
 [myButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

For iOS 6 or higher it's

```
 [myButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

as explained in [tyler53's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968263/468724)

**Swift:**

```
myButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

**Swift 4.x and above**

```
myButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: It has became NSTextAlignment in later versions of iOS.

Comment: thas code not work, the best answer is @joetjah `myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;`

Comment: The question explicitly mentions **IB**, as in **Interface Builder**. This is _not_ the correct answer, as it requires coding.

Comment: **Swift 4:**   myButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center

Comment: 'Center' has been renamed to 'center'

Answer (score 110):

Use the line:

```
myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
```

This should center the content (horizontally).

And if you want to set the text inside the label to the center as well, use:

`[labelOne setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];`

If you want to use IB, I've got a small example here which is linked in XCode 4 but should provide enough detail (also mind, on top of that properties screen it shows the property tab. You can find the same tabs in XCode 3.x):
[image]

Comment: thanks...but I don't want to set it through IB. :( that's my last option of doing that...

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore: No problem. To set it in IB, you should click on the label, then in the Attributes Inspector, set Alignment to "Center". In my IB (XCode 4), it has 3 icons showing the alignment of text. Obviously, you should pick the middle one then.

Comment: can you please send me the screen shot... Is this the label of the Button or you have draged the UILabel from the library??? I suppose it UILabel not button's label

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore: Hey, check out the screenshot I added. I have indeed mistaken the kind of labels you use, I was still thinking on UILabel instead of the text in UIButton. The screenshot shows how to align on the UIButton through IB.

Comment: Yeah I have done it but it just align the button's content.... :( try multi line title you will find that...

Comment: UITextAlignmentCenter has been deprecated.  Use NSTextAlignmentCenter now.

Comment: @OCRickard Feel free to add explanation, I'm not actively working with Objective-C or iOS development anymore.

Comment: Wouldn't let me edit, but NSTextAlignmentCenter has taken the place of UITextAlignmentCenter.  They mean exactly the same thing tho.  https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSTextAlignment

Answer (score 27):

For UIButton you should use:-

```
[btn setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
```

Answer (score 16):

For ios 8 and Swift

`btn.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center`

or

`btn.titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center`

Answer (score 15):

**For swift 4, xcode 9**

```
myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
```

Comment: I set myButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0 and it caused the label within the button to center, so I was trying to figure out how to align the text to the left within the button and this worked, setting it to .left however.

Answer (score 13):

For those of you who are now using iOS 6 or higher, UITextAlignmentCenter has been deprecated.  It is now NSTextAlignmentCenter

EXAMPLE: `mylabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;` Works perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that btn refers to a UIButton, to change a multi-line caption to be centered horizontally, you can use the following statement in iOS 6 or later:

```
self.btn.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 4:

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    sender.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    sender.setTitle("Some centered String", for:UIControlState.normal)
}
```

Comment: use one "?" in sender.titleLabel? instead "??"

Answer (score 4):

`UITextAlignmentCenter` is deprecated in iOS6

Instead you can use this code:

`btn.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlinmentCenter;`

Comment: There is no property for UIButton callee textAlignment.

Comment: There is no such property for UIButton in iOS

Comment: He means button.titleLabel.textAlignment

Answer (score 4):

Actually you **can** do it in **interface builder**.

You should set **Title** to `"Attributed"` and then choose center alignment.

Comment: If it is attributed we can not set the textcolor, font  etc through Storyboard.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 3.0

```
btn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Like this :

```
yourButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
yourButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from storyboard.
Select your button. Set Line Break 'Word Wrap', Set your title 'Plain' to 'Attributed'. 
Select 'Center alignment'. This part is important => Click ...(More) Button. And select line breaking mode to 'Character Wrap'.

Answer (score 1):

UIButton will not support setTextAlignment. So You need to go with setContentHorizontalAlignment for button text alignment

For your reference

```
[buttonName setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
```