# set uibutton text alignment storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that in code I can do `[myButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentRight];` but how would I do this in Storyboard in **User Defined Runtime Attributes**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to make UIButton's text alignment center? Using IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712937/how-to-make-uibuttons-text-alignment-center-using-ib)

This post shows how to do it in storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can set the alignment of content (text or image) within your UIButton in the Attributes Inspector Panel.

The menu is "Control", you can set Horizontal & Vertical Alignment

[image]

Comment: How to set padding with that? I mean when i did this, the button text just sticks to the left of its view with no padding and that looks odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can also adjust the constraints of the content, title or image in the size inspector of the button:

[image]

In my case, I was only able to really centralize the character "+" and "-" after setting a value for the bottom of the title.