# How can we fix UItextfields text and UIbuttons title labels exactly at center position

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in ios and i am trying to insert UItextfield "text" data exactly at center of the y-axis as like below textfield image

And i would like to insert UIbutton "titleLabel text" exactly center of x-axis and center of y-axis as like below button image for this i tried lot but i did not get result please help me some one

### my code:-

```
 [self.TripIdTxt setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
    self.TripIdTxt.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    self.TripIdTxt.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.TripIdTxt.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
    self.TripIdTxt.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self.TripIdTxt setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
    [self.TripIdTxt setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
    self.TripIdTxt.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.TripIdTxt.font = [UIFont fontWithName:bitter_Regular size:14];
```

[image]

Comment: Did u tried label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter ?

Comment: i can only set title label center of x axis but i am not able set that center of y-axis also using your answer

Comment: OK, maybe you should try to work with NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
 style.minimumLineHeight = "YOUR FONTSIZE" + 5;
 style.maximumLineHeight = YOUR FONTSIZE" + 5;
 NSDictionary *attributtes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style}; yourLabel.setAttributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", attributes:attributtes]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set

for `UIButton`

```
yourbtnName.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

for y-axis

```
[yourbtnName setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
```

for X-axis

```
[yourbtnName setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
```

for `UITextFields`

```
yourtextfieldName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

diectly you can access in storyboard like

[image]

for additional information see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712937/how-to-make-uibuttons-text-alignment-center-using-ib)

**Padding with TextField**

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
TripIdTxt.leftView = paddingView;
self. TripIdTxt.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

or else use Transform

```
TripIdTxt.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: yes andbu.kartik but using your answer i can only set title label center of x axis but i am not able set that center of y-axis also

Comment: @Anil -- check the updated answer, it apply for textfield also

Comment: @Anil -- have a happy day my bro

Comment: Anbu.Kartik one small help when i apply leftpadding view for UItextfild agin problem is coming i mean textfield text is not set at the center of x-axis    [self.TripIdTxt setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
    self.TripIdTxt.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    self.TripIdTxt.leftView = paddingView;

Comment: why can you tell me reson please?

Comment: if you need to change the entire textfiled text as center the above answer is working fine , if you want to chnage  the some left use Padding check the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92692/discussion-between-anil-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

Set the text alignmaent center of your lable property .

```
mainlabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 0):

u set its alignment using xib by

[image]

u can also set its vertical alignment using xib by

[image]

Programmatically U can set Content's vertical alignment for textfield as well as button as

```
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
txtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
```

Hope it helps.
Happy Coding.. :)